# nodejs declare array of objects with dynamic size

Tags: node.js

Here's how I declare my array of objects:

```
let arrayOfObjects = [{ _id:0, names:'' }];
```

And I want to assign the values like below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < kelasList.length; i++){
  for (var j = 0; j < absentees[i].length; j++){                    
    arrayOfObjects[i]._id = absentees[i][j]._id
    arrayOfObjects[i].names = absentees[i][j].firstName + " " + absentees[i][j].lastName
  }
}
```

Running the code above will return

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property '_id' of undefined at line
```

which basically points to the line

```
arrayOfObjects[i]._id
```

But it will assign the value without any problem, if I write

```
arrayOfObjects[0]._id
```

instead of

```
arrayOfObjects[i]._id
```

My assumption was `let arrayOfObjects = [{ _id:0, names:'' }];` would create an array of objects, so I would be able to access/set its values with

```
arrayOfObjects[i]._id
```

but it seems `let arrayOfObjects = [{ _id:0, names:'' }];` here will only create a single array of object. So currently for me to pass more values, I will need to declare it something like

```
let arrayOfObjects = [{ _id:0, names:'' },{ _id:0, names:'' },{ _id:0, names:'' },{ _id:0, names:'' },{ _id:0, names:'' }];
```

But of course, this isn't feasible because I don't know what should my array size be. So actually how should I declare the array of objects that can contain dynamic size of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply check if the element already exists in the array and if it doesn't, create it.

```
let arrayOfObjects = [];

for (var i = 0; i < kelasList.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < absentees[i].length; j++) {
    if (!arrayOfObjects[i]) {
      arrayOfObjects[i] = {
        _id: 0,
        names: ''
      };
    }
    arrayOfObjects[i]._id = absentees[i][j]._id
    arrayOfObjects[i].names = absentees[i][j].firstName + " " + absentees[i][j].lastName
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting `arrayOfObjects[i]._id`, you are setting the attribute `_id` on an already existing object `arrayOfObjects[i]`. But for i >= 1, this object doesn't exist.

Instead, you need to set the whole object in the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < kelasList.length; i++){
  for (var j = 0; j < absentees[i].length; j++){                    
    arrayOfObjects[i] = {
        _id: absentees[i][j]._id, 
        names: absentees[i][j].firstName + " " + absentees[i][j].lastName}
    }
}
```

This will work just fine, but will replace the **whole object** at the index `i`. If instead you want to set the `_id` and `names` attribute of an object that could already be existing with different keys (say, address), you would check if the object exists:

```
for (var i = 0; i < kelasList.length; i++){
  for (var j = 0; j < absentees[i].length; j++){ 
    let id = absentees[i][j]._id;
    let names = arrayOfObjects[i].names = absentees[i][j].firstName + " " + absentees[i][j].lastName; 

    if(arrayOfObjets[i]){
      arrayOfObjects[i]._id = id;
      arrayOfObjects[i].names = names;
    }else{         
      arrayOfObjects[i] = {
        _id: absentees[i][j]._id, 
        names: absentees[i][j].firstName + " " + absentees[i][j].lastName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is one last problem with your code. You are iterating over **i**, then over **j**, and are setting `arrayOfObjects[i]`. This means that your double loop is basically the same thing as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < kelasList.length; i++){
  let lastAbsentee = absentees[i][absentees[i].length-1];
  arrayOfObjects[i]._id = lastAbsentee._id
  arrayOfObjects[i].names = lastAbsentee.firstName + " " + lastAbsentee.lastName
}
```

Are you sure that is what you want to do? Somehow I would be doubting it.

Comment: I would also address the odd iterating over `kelasList` which just seems to be `absentees` with extra steps.

Answer (score 1):

- Your `arrayOfObjects` has a size of `1` when you initialize it, but then you look into `arrayOfObjects[i]` after `i === 0` which cause the `undefined` behavior since there are no items there (yet).
- In your `for` loop, you're also *overwriting* on `arrayOfObjects[i]` multiple times (`j` times to for precision).

Try using this

```
let arrayOfObjects = [];

for (var i = 0; i < absentees.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < absentees[i].length; j++) {
        arrayOfObjects.push({
            _id: absentees[i][[j]._id,
            names: absentees[i][j].firstName + " " + absentees[i][j].lastName
        });
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** The iteration logic may be subject to change since I didn't really get your intention from your code. The "adding items to the arrray" part is good though.